# CakePHP: get current controller name in a model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm creating a behaviour that needs to log the current controller name. How can I get the current controller name from within a model in CakePHP?

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it's not pretty but worked for me. I just use the $_REQUEST['url'] and catch de controller name by url. The downside of this solution, is that if you have a route different for default, this solution will not work... anyone have a better approach ?

Comment: Depending on what you try to accomplish you could write a component.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is pretty old, but the proper solution here would be:

`$this->params['controller']`

For more information on the 'params' attribute: 
http://book.cakephp.org/view/963/The-Parameters-Attribute-params

Comment: $this->params is not accessible inside Model

Comment: @rizidoro The model should have no awareness of any other MVC aspect than itself. A better way to do this would be getting the controller name in the controller and passing it to the model as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. if u only need the name of the controller.

```
Inflector::pluralize($this->name);
```

Comment: Downvoted because you cannot derive a controller's name from a model name as a model can be used from different controllers.

Comment: @dhofestet : thankz for correcting.i didn't thought of that case. :(

Answer (score 2):

```
$GLOBALS['Dispatcher']->params['controller']
```

will give you the controller name

Answer (score 0):

For anybody revisiting this question and using CakePHP 3.x:

```php
$this->request->getParam('controller')
```

Answer (score -1):

One of PHP's Magic Constants is `__CLASS__` which will return the class name of the object it is within. This may get you what you need.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Magic Constants and Methods are fun.

Comment: I'm curious why someone downvoted this?  It's the start of a solution that looks like it would work (even if it's nonoptimal).  Please leave a comment if you downvote.

Comment: I wish I knew too. Probably there is some way in Cake. I don't use cake, so I don't know. Maybe Cake doesn't uses classes for controllers? Who knows.

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer, but doesn't this just return the name of the behavior?

Comment: yeap...this returns the name of the behavior

Comment: Hence the "may" in my answer. Since many frameworks chose to wrap the controller in a class. (CodeIgniter for example) If Cake doesn't, but does something else to make Controllers work, then yeah, this won't help.

Comment: A controller is a class in CakePHP, though a behavior is also a class.